# Health probe marks instances as unhealthy but the aren't

Tags: node.js, load-balancing, azure-vm-scale-set

I use a VM scale set for my node application. My app has an action which is public accessible via `www.mydomain.com/api/healthcheck` and prints just some json.
When I configure my health probe to use `TCP` protocol, everything works fine and also my api returns me the expected json (and status 200).
However, when I now switch my health probe to use `HTTP` and path=`/api/healthcheck`, my website isn't accesible anymore (`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`... I guess the loadbalancer takes out all instances because the health probe tells him that every instance is unhealthy)

I use nginx in front of my node app, but I also tried (for testing) to configure my LoadBalancer to route port 80 to backendport 8080 (where my node app is running on every machine, so I can avoid nginx proxy). But I get the same behaviour.

I'm out of ideas why my custom health check doesn't work. Hope you can help.

---

Edit:
For testing, I did the following:

- run another nodejs app on port 3000 on every VM, which just prints "hello world" (without nginx proxy!)
- create a LB rule for port 3000 and also configure my NSG to allow :3000 for all
- at the beginning, my health probe is configured to use `tcp`
- result: `mydoamin.com:3000/hello` is available (prints *hello* and returns 200)
- now I configure my health probe to use `http`-protocol, port `3000` and location `/hello`.
- result: my whole web app isn't available anymore

Comment: Does the HTTP health check fail even using port 80? Or only when using port 8080? Also, is it possible your site has a redirect from the http endpoint to the equivalent https endpoint?

Comment: It fails also on port 80. Yes there was a redirect to https but I deleted this rule for test cases but again I get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see your server's code so its hard to figure out.
If you shared some code it would be easier.

So lets try to analyze the situation :

## Initial Check

> Connection to the instances has timed out

Try to perform the following command from your machines terminal

```
curl –I private-IP-address-of-the-instance:port/health-check-target-page
```

now depending on the otucome we have different possible causes...

## Initial Check Result : non-200 response

- No target page is configured on the instance.
- The value of the Content-Length header in the response is not set.
- The application is not configured to receive requests from the load
  balancer or to return a 200 response code.

## Initial Check Result : able to connect directly to the instance

- The instance is failing to respond within the configured response
  timeout period.
- The instance is under significant load and is taking longer than your configured response timeout period to respond.
- If you are using an HTTP or an HTTPS connection and the health check
  is being performed on a target page specified in the ping path field
  (for example, HTTP:80/index.html), the target page might be taking
  longer to respond than your configured timeout.

## Other : Instance is not receiving traffic from the load balancer

**Problem: The security group for the instance is blocking the traffic from the load balancer.**

Do a packet capture on the instance to verify the issue. Use the following command:

```
tcpdump port health-check-port
```

Comment: Thank you! I will follow these steps and let you know if it works (probably tomorrow)

Comment: It works now! `curl –I private-IP-address-of-the-instance:port/health-check-target-page` told me, that nginx couldn't identify the server name - because in all my `server{}`-blocks I have this line: `server_name *.mydomain.com;`. Now I just added this to my nginx config: `server{ listen 81; location = /my/healthcheck {...} }`, set up a NSG for port 81 and configured my health probe to use port `81` and path `/my/healthcheck`